Can't access tracks audio features using Spotipy fetching from Spotify API
Doing a project in university data science course and I'm working with API-s for the first time. I need to fetch different data about tracks using Spotify API, but I have encountered a problem early on. I can get access to some basic data about tracks popularity, duration, etc but I get 403 error when trying to fetch audio-features aswell. As far as I have searched for help on the web, apparently I have insufficient permissions in the scope of my Spotify access token. But I don't know how to get this problem fixed.
I attempted to fetch audio features (e.g., tempo, danceability, energy) for the same tracks using sp.audio_features(track_ids). This is where the issue arises.
When I run the code, I receive an error, and the audio features are not retrieved.

Error: "HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com... with Params: {} returned 403 due to None"

from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pandas as pd
    
load_dotenv()
client_id = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET")
redirect_uri = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI")

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope="user-top-read"
)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    
# Fetch data
top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=10)
track_data = []
track_ids = []
for item in top_tracks['items']:
    track_ids.append(item['id'])
    track_data.append({
        'track_id': item['id'],
        'track_name': item['name'],
        'artists': ", ".join(artist['name'] for artist in item['artists']),
        'popularity': item['popularity'],
        'explicit': item['explicit'],
        'duration_ms': item['duration_ms']
    })

# Fetch audio features
try:
    audio_features = sp.audio_features(track_ids) # Causing errors
    audio_features_df = pd.DataFrame(audio_features)
    df = pd.DataFrame(track_data)
    df = pd.merge(df, audio_features_df, left_on='track_id', right_on='id')
except: 
    print("Can not access audio features")
    df = pd.DataFrame(track_data)
    
df.head(10)


Spotify deprecated several API endpoints on November 27th 2024. The get-audio-features was one of those endpoints.
This in turn affected spotipy as well.
